# Open XML document in echo

Tags: php, xml

Good, again I ask your help, I have an xml document (http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml) which provides the name of songs played.

What I'm trying is to remove the information from xml with php echo, I realized a php code but must be wrong, because it gives me nothing so I came to ask your help in solving this problem.

```html
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
print $xml->Event->Song['title'];
echo '';
?>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
print $xml->Event->Song->Artist['name'];
echo '';
?>
```

Someone I can help?

Thank you before too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplexml does not see root element. Write it so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://inlivefm.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
foreach($xml->Song as $item)
   echo $item->Artist['name'] . " - " . $item['title'] ."<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you, this work perfectly, liked to make an issue if you know me answer.
The document will adding more songs that played on the radio, what I wanted to know is if there is any way in PHP echo removing information only the last song played?

Comment: i am not clear undestanding your question. Try to answer so: you can get array `$a = $xml->Song;` and take the items you want from `$item = $a[0];` upto `$item = $a[count($a)];`

Comment: With the data that you indicated I will try to make the experience, but what I meant was me and clarified this to work, thank you!